# $\lim_{x \to 0^+} (\cos x)^\frac{1}{x^2} $

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (\cos x)^\frac{1}{x^2} $$

When I attempt to do this I get stuck in an endless loop of L'Hoptial's rule.
Is there any way to solve this without using  de Moivre's theorem ( We haven't learned that)

edit: now I know that the limit DNE, I'd like to know how to solve another case for this function:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} (\cos x)^\frac{1}{x^2} $$

Comment: Where is $n$ in the inside expression? And you need to fix the formatting.

Comment: sorry about that; i'm not very good at mathjax

Comment: Well, pretty obviously, this limit can't exist since it is $0$ for infinitely many values of $x$ and $1$ for infinitely many values of $x$. Perhaps you really want $x\to 0$? That's a more interesting case...

Comment: hm, that might be good to know as well. I think I did this thinking of x-> 0, I'll add that one up to see if there is an answer.

Comment: I'm thinking the second answer is $1/\sqrt e$. It's essentially because for $x$ small, $\cos x\approx 1-x^2/2$, but you'll need to be more precise than that...

Comment: Since $\cos x$ is even, you can actually take $x\to 0$ rather than $x\to 0+$. $\cos x$ is close to $1$ whether $x$ is positive or negative.

Answer (score 3):

Just use logarithm-exponent identity you can get the answer.
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}=\cos(x)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}=e^{\frac{\ln(\cos(x))}{x^2}}
\end{equation}
Then we just need to calculate the limitation of the exponent item.
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\ln(\cos(x))}{x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{-\tan(x)}{2x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{-x}{2x}=-\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
At the second step from bottom, I use the equivalent infinitesimal that $\tan(x)\sim x$ .
Thus, the limitation is $e^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: Isn't $tan(x)$ equal to zero?

Comment: Note, you can't even really take $\log \cos(x)$ since $\cos(x)$ can be negative. Indeed this function isn't clearly well-defined as a real valued function.

Comment: @Shuri $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x} = 1$ is the theorem he is using here.

Comment: Well, $\cos x$ is positive when $x$ is close to $0$, so that's not really a problem

Comment: @ThomasAndrews To calculate the limitation, we can assume $x$ in a right neighborhood of $0$. Then $\cos(x)$ is positive.

Comment: Are you using L'Hopital's rule for the second limit? Another way would be to note that $$\ln (\cos x) = \ln (1 + \cos x - 1) \approx \cos x - 1 \approx 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} - 1 = -\frac{x^2}{2}$$

Comment: @dani_s Yes, I have. Your deduction is also a good method!

Comment: @Lion You can't assume $\cos x>0$ when $x>0$ and $x\to\infty$. You can assume it for $x\to0+$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, I just only solve the limitation when $x$ go to $0$. When $x$ go to infinity, the limitation is do not exist because the function is not always meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

If $L$ is the desired limit then $$\begin{aligned}\log L &= \log\left(\lim_{x \to 0}(\cos x)^{1/x^{2}}\right)\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\log\left((\cos x)^{1/x^{2}}\right)\text{ (by continuity of }\log)\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log \cos x}{x^{2}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log (1 + \cos x - 1)}{x^{2}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log (1 + \cos x - 1)}{\cos x - 1}\cdot\frac{\cos x - 1}{x^{2}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}1\cdot\frac{\cos x - 1}{x^{2}}\\
&= -2\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^{2}(x/2)}{(x/2)^{2}}\cdot\frac{(x/2)^{2}}{x^{2}}\\
&= -2\cdot\frac{1}{4} = -\frac{1}{2}\end{aligned}$$ It now follows that $L = e^{-1/2} = 1/\sqrt{e}$.